# MySQL Error Code 1241

Tags: mysql, sql

I just tried to use the `IF-ELSE with SELECT` of mySQL. I know there's a syntax error here but can't find it. It's returning `Error Code 1241. Operand should contain 1 column(s)` on mySQL Workbench.

I don't see any error or maybe I just can't find it. What could be causing this?

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `addCurriculum`(    
    IN p_curcName varchar(100), 
    IN p_description TEXT, 
    IN p_yearLevel VARCHAR(50),
    IN p_syStart INT, 
    IN p_syEnd INT, 
    IN p_creator VARCHAR(50)            )
BEGIN
    IF 
        (SELECT name,description,yearLevel,syStart,syEnd
        FROM curriculum 
        WHERE 
            name        =       p_curcName 
        AND description =       p_description
        AND yearLevel   =       p_yearLevel 
        AND syStart     =       p_syStart 
        AND syEnd       =       p_syEnd 
        AND creator     =       p_creator )

    THEN --

    BEGIN
        SELECT 'Curriculum you are trying to add already exists';
    END;

        ELSE

            BEGIN
                INSERT INTO curriculum(name, description, yearLevel, syStart, syEnd, creator)
                VALUES(p_curcName,p_description,p_yearLevel,p_syStart,p_syEnd,p_creator);
            END;

    END IF;

END
```

I'd appreciate any help since I'm new to the language. I just started learning Transaction and Procedures.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so I just have to add `EXISTS`

```
IF EXISTS
        (SELECT name,description,yearLevel,syStart,syEnd
        FROM curriculum 
        WHERE 
            name        =       p_curcName 
        AND description =       p_description
        AND yearLevel   =       p_yearLevel 
        AND syStart     =       p_syStart 
        AND syEnd       =       p_syEnd 
        AND creator     =       p_creator )
```

I don't know how `MERGE` works so I guess I'll have to read more.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for IF EXISTS, but there are a number of ways of upserting  (UPdatinSERT) using IF and Merge, lots of them in SO :)

Comment: Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 0):

```
IF 
        (SELECT name,description,yearLevel,syStart,syEnd
```

doesn't make sense; it is expecting just one column for the if to test.

Perhaps you want `IF (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ...)`